# Infinite loop because a variable keeps getting redeclared to its original value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react I tried to recreate the well known game "Minesweeper" and in my journey I wanted to randomly generate where the bombs will spawn.
So I got a 12x12 matrix and 40 bombs for which I randomly generate *x* and *y* coordinates. To not be unfair I generate the bombs only after the first square is selected.

Now the code isn't complete but I guess because after the first phase of the game (mentioned earlier) I do a re-render by pressing the submit button, the variable `nrbomb` is never decremented to **0** because it will always be re-declared as **40**

Tried to declare it outside the function and I've even tried to set up a `useState` for that value, but it keeps getting re-declared and creating an infinite loop.

**How can I declare an unchangeable variable?**

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

const square = {
  bomb: 0,
  viz: 0,
}
let nrbomb = 40

function App() {
  const n = 12
  let v = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let arr = []
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) arr.push(square)
    v.push(arr)
  }

  const [inc, change_inc] = useState(0)
  const [mine_grid, change_mine_grid] = useState(v)
  const [cx, change_cx] = useState(0)
  const [cy, change_cy] = useState(0)
  const [rendergame, change_render_game] = useState(0)

  if (inc == 0) {
    return (
      <div className="all">
        <div className="grid_container">
          {mine_grid.map((arr) => {
            return arr.map((e) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: 'green',
                    width: '50px',
                    height: '50px',
                    margin: '5px',
                  }}
                ></div>
              )
            })
          })}
        </div>
        <h6>for x:</h6>
        <input
          value={cx}
          onChange={(e) => {
            change_cx(e.target.value)
          }}
        ></input>
        <h6>for y:</h6>
        <input
          value={cy}
          onChange={(e) => {
            change_cy(e.target.value)
          }}
        ></input>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            let new_grid = mine_grid
            new_grid[cx][cy].viz = 1
            change_mine_grid(new_grid)
            change_inc(1)
          }}
        >
          Submit move
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  if (inc == 1 && rendergame == 0) {
    while (nrbomb != 0) {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      console.log(x, y, nrbomb)
      if (mine_grid[x][y].bomb === 0 && mine_grid[x][y].viz == 0) {
        nrbomb = nrbomb - 1
        let new_grid = mine_grid
        new_grid[x][y].bomb = 1
        change_mine_grid(new_grid)
      }
    }
  }
  
  return <div className="grid_container"></div>
}

export default App
```

Comment: Calling a state setter function in the regular body of your component will pretty much always cause problems. Is there a reason why this doesn't happen in the onClick handler for submission when inc == 0?

Comment: Not to mention it's unclear whether you call change_inc/ change_render_game beyond the onClick handler, thus leading your conditional if statement to always fire and therefore always trigger a rerender (hence your infinite rerender issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a refactor of what you originally created, with the major differences being:

1. When the mine grid is updated we forcefully recreate the mine grid object (array of arrays) to ensure that React recognizes the state change
2. When mines are not currently placed, the onClick handler for a mine cell will handle creating mines on the first click via the `createMines` function. This way state is only ever changed as a result of an action, and not on every render.

Sample:

```
const totalBombs = 40;
const square = { bomb: 0, viz: 0 };
const boardSideSize = 12;
// this is an easy way for us to recreate the mine_grid
const createDefaultGrid = () =>
  new Array(boardSideSize)
    .fill(0)
    .map(() => new Array(boardSideSize).fill(0).map(() => ({ ...square })));

// we call this once we want to initialize the game and place bombs
const createMineGridFromPositions = (minePositions) => {
  const grid = createDefaultGrid();
  minePositions.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
    grid[x][y].bomb = 1;
  });
  return grid;
};

// this is used to change mine_grid state. we create a new grid and return it
const createMineGrid = (grid) => {
  const new_grid = createDefaultGrid();
  new_grid.forEach((row, x) =>
    row.forEach((cell, y) => {
      cell.bomb = grid[x][y].bomb;
      cell.viz = grid[x][y].viz;
    })
  );
  return new_grid;
};

function App() {
  const [mine_grid, change_mine_grid] = useState(createDefaultGrid());
  const [mines_placed, change_mines_placed] = useState(false);
  const [game_over, set_game_over] = useState(false);

  const createMines = (firstX, firstY) => {
    const totalMines = [];
    while (totalMines.length < totalBombs) {
      const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSideSize);
      const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardSideSize);
      console.log(x, y, totalMines);
      const gridPos = mine_grid[x][y];
      const sameAsFirstPos = x === firstX && y === firstY;
      if (
        gridPos.bomb === 0 &&
        gridPos.viz === 0 &&
        !sameAsFirstPos &&
        !totalMines.find((mines) => mines.x === x && mines.y === y)
      ) {
        totalMines.push({ x, y });
      }
    }
    const newGrid = createMineGridFromPositions(totalMines);
    newGrid[firstX][firstY].viz = 1;
    change_mine_grid(newGrid);
  };

  const clickHandler = (cell, x, y) => {
    if (cell.viz) {
      // if visible already this is a no-op. do nothing
      return;
    }

    if (!mines_placed) {
      createMines(x, y);
      change_mines_placed(true);
    } else {
      const new_mine_grid = createMineGrid(mine_grid);
      new_mine_grid[x][y].viz = 1;
      if (new_mine_grid[x][y].bomb) {
        set_game_over(true);
      }
      change_mine_grid(new_mine_grid);
    }
  }

  if (game_over) {
    // can render something different in this game state
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="all">
      <div className="grid_container">
        {mine_grid.map((row, x) =>
          row.map((cell, y) => (
            <div
              key={`${x}-${y}`}
              style={{
                background:
                  cell.bomb && cell.viz ? "red" : cell.viz ? "green" : "gray",
                width: "50px",
                height: "50px",
                margin: "5px",
              }}
              onClick={() => clickHandler(cell, x, y)}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you refactor this further you might find it's actually easier to use the `minePositions` approach for handling state for visible/ bomb cells instead of maintaining state for the entire grid.

Comment: this is not really what i had in mind but i will study the code and come up with better code that should replicate minesweeper. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a `while` loop, use a `for`:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'

const square = {
  bomb: 0,
  viz: 0,
}
let nrbomb = 40

function App() {
  const n = 12
  let v = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let arr = []
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) arr.push(square)
    v.push(arr)
  }

  const [inc, change_inc] = useState(0)
  const [mine_grid, change_mine_grid] = useState(v)
  const [cx, change_cx] = useState(0)
  const [cy, change_cy] = useState(0)
  const [rendergame, change_render_game] = useState(0)

  if (inc == 0) {
    return (
      <div className="all">
        <div className="grid_container">
          {mine_grid.map((arr) => {
            return arr.map((e) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: 'green',
                    width: '50px',
                    height: '50px',
                    margin: '5px',
                  }}
                ></div>
              )
            })
          })}
        </div>
        <h6>for x:</h6>
        <input
          value={cx}
          onChange={(e) => {
            change_cx(e.target.value)
          }}
        ></input>
        <h6>for y:</h6>
        <input
          value={cy}
          onChange={(e) => {
            change_cy(e.target.value)
          }}
        ></input>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            let new_grid = mine_grid
            new_grid[cx][cy].viz = 1
            change_mine_grid(new_grid)
            change_inc(1)
          }}
        >
          Submit move
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  if (inc == 1 && rendergame == 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nrbomb; i++) {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      console.log(x, y, nrbomb)

      if (!mine_grid[x][y].bomb === 0 || mine_grid[x][y].viz != 0) {
        // In case it's not placing the bomb, decrease "i" back and skip
        i--
        continue
      }
        let new_grid = mine_grid
        new_grid[x][y].bomb = 1
        change_mine_grid(new_grid)
    }
  }
  
  return <div className="grid_container"></div>
}

export default App
```

Comment: while this solves the issue of the infinite while loop, it doesn't solve infinite rerendering issues because of the usage change_mine_grid in the body of the component

Comment: oh so what you are implying is to call a function to do that instead of just calling the state setter function , is that right? @G1N

Comment: About to post an answer with regards to this but yes you're absolutely correct; you'll see momentarily

Comment: it still doesnt work even after i put them in a function
```if (inc == 1 && rendergame == 0) {
    let new_grid = mine_grid
    while (nrbomb != 0) {
      let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * n)
      console.log(x, y, nrbomb)
      if (new_grid[x][y].bomb === 0 && new_grid[x][y].viz == 0) {
        new_grid[x][y].bomb = 1
      }
    }
    ;() => {
      change_render_game(1)
      change_mine_grid(new_grid)
    }
  }
```